# Specify hinting for a certain font

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I am using Droid fonts were possible. I have KDE.

Droid fonts look perfect with full hinting, but Ubuntu font do not.

Ubuntu font looks good with no or slight hinting, but then Droid fonts look bad.

[image: Full hinting]
[image: No hinting]

[image: Full hinting]
[image: No hinting]

Is there a possibility to specify hinting type per font family?

I tried the following in `fonts.conf`, but it doesn't work:

```
 <match target="pattern" name="family">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Ubuntu</string>
  </test>
  <edit binding="strong" mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintnone</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintfull</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like font matching was wrong. This works:

```
<!-- Special handling for Droid Font family -->
<match target="font">
    <test name="family" qual="any" compare="contains">
        <string>Droid</string>
    </test>

    <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle"><const>hintfull</const></edit>
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
    <edit name="rgba" mode="assign"><const>rgb</const></edit>
</match>

<!-- Special handling for Ubuntu Font family -->
<match target="font">
    <test name="family" qual="any" compare="contains">
        <string>Ubuntu</string>
    </test>

    <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle"><const>hintnone</const></edit>
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
    <edit name="rgba" mode="assign"><const>rgb</const></edit>
</match>
```